# what is the alternative for 'using a dict on a Series for aggregation'

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, series

I used agg function to calculate the average value of CENSUS2010POP grouped by STNAME. Inside the agg function, I used a dictionary with {} to name the new column for the average values (details in the codes below)
The codes work well but Jupyter Notebook gave me a warning

FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation
is deprecated and will be removed in a future version

I wonder what is the new way to do this.

I'm running this on the newest Jupyter Notebook, with python 3, installed from Anaconda3

the method I am using now is like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
df = (df.where(df['SUMLEV']==50)
     .dropna()
     .set_index('STNAME')
     .groupby(level = 0)['CENSUS2010POP']
     .agg({'avg' : np.average}) )

df
```

But this method is deprecated and will be removed in the future as the warning said

The result should be like this (which is the result from the codes above)

```
                avg
STNAME  
Alabama         71339.343284
Alaska          24490.724138
Arizona         426134.466667
Arkansas        38878.906667
California      642309.586207
Colorado        78581.187500
Connecticut     446762.125000
Delaware        299311.333333
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the documentation for `pandas.DataFrame.agg` it says `agg` can take a function, list, str, or dict as input. So you could directly pass the function `np.average` and give it as a column label.

```
df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
df = (df.where(df['SUMLEV']==50)
     .dropna()
     .set_index('STNAME')
df['avg'] = df.groupby(level = 0)['CENSUS2010POP']
     .agg(np.average) )
```